# What type of NN should be used for a turn-based game (with direct access to data)?

Tags: neural-network

I am very intrigued and I decided to do a little project in my free time to get a hold of it.The goal of my project is to make a NN that can play a turn-based game.

I have searched for a bit about this subject and all I could find was NNs that use images of the game to make decisions, but what if I already have the game's data directly? What type of NN would work best in this situation?

I am hoping you can point me a bit to the right direction if possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite broad so it is not easy to give a direct answer.  However, a simple approach and a good introduction to machine learning would be to use a **[Multilayer Perceptron (MLP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron)**.  This is one of the most basic and fundamental neural network architectures.

You will also want to read about **[Backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation)**, which is the standard method of training such algorithms.

Here are some **code examples/libraries** (in no particular order) that can get you started:

- [Keras - (Python)](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py)
- [Theano - (Python)](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/mlp.html)
- [DeepLearning4J - (Java)](https://deeplearning4j.org/multilayerperceptron)
- [Caffe  - (C++/Python/Matlab)](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/)
- [TensorFlow - (C++/Python)](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/)
- [Weka - (Java)](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/MultilayerPerceptron.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'll dig into these asap! For info, what kind of informations could make the question less broad?

Comment: It would help to know what game you are specifically working on and what data you have available.

Comment: Well an example game that I can think of is Wakfu and the data would be the raw data of the game (that gets sent by sockets) which represent for example the character's infos, monsters positions, healths etc..

Comment: I am not familiar with this game, but it seems that you will probably be interested in reinforcement learning (RL).  You may also be interested in genetic algorithms (GA).  This seems like a challenging introduction to machine learning.  If you find that it is too much, it might be worth exploring games where people have extensively implemented machine learning such as checkers and chess.  There would be significantly more online resources to help you.